# Samba share write

Tags: samba

I have a problem writing to a folder that I share using samba on my ubuntu machine. I can access the files from my Windows 7 machine, but I cannot write to the folder, any suggestions?

Thank You very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Samba executes the file operations as a local unix user on the server you are running samba on. Make sure that you have this user defined to the one you want in smb.conf and that this user has write access to the directory/files.

you can see the [full example here](http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-Guide/simple.html#charitynet)

but basically what you want to do is:

```
[someshare]
comment = Some Share
path = /path/to/share
read only = No
force user = someuser
force group = somegroup
guest ok = Yes
create mask = 0775
```

then you just need to do:

```
chown -R someuser:somegroup /path/to/share
chmod -R 775 /path/to/share
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to use a nice application sadms that is in the ubuntu software center to accomplish what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Check those two things first:

- make sure the checkbox "Allow others to create and delete files in this folder" in the properties of your shared folder is checked OR
- make sure to use a known user account on the ubuntu machine to access the share